# Tampermonkey script not updating

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey

I am having issues getting my script to auto-update. If I force a check for an update, then it picks up the new version just fine. However, I am unable to get this to automatically notify me whenever a new update is available.

My script has the following metadata:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         PortalScript
// @namespace    PortalScript
// @version      2.1.0.9
// @description  Contains customizations to be applied to the portal
// @author       Tristan Lee
// @match        https://test-support.portal.dev
// @grant        none
// @downloadURL https://rawgit.com/tristanlee85/supportportal/master/supportportal.js
// @updateURL https://rawgit.com/tristanlee85/supportportal/master/supportportal.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

Tampermonkey is set to check for updates every hour. However, the version in the repository may be 2.1.0.10, but after hours since the version change, I am never notified that an update is available.

I also don't believe `@updateURL` is necessary here since `@downloadURL` is specified, but I added it as a check since only having `@downloadURL` didn't work either.

Comment: answer seems to be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023717/why-is-usage-of-the-downloadurl-updateurl-keys-called-unusual-and-how-do-they

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is usage of the downloadURL & updateURL keys called unusual and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023717/why-is-usage-of-the-downloadurl-updateurl-keys-called-unusual-and-how-do-they)